# Dynamic Drop Down List - PHP and Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am wanting to create a dynamic drop down list based on mysql database and tables. I searched around the net and the closest I came was to http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/ajax_drop_down_list.php

I have implimented this code as per example, the first drop down box works correctly however the second does not get populated once a 'category' is chosen.

The code is:

**main.php**

```
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

  function AjaxFunction(cat_id) {
    var httpxml;
    try {
      // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
      httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {
      // Internet Explorer
      try {
        httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
      } catch (e) {
        try {
          httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
          alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    function stateck() {
      if (httpxml.readyState == 4) {
        var myarray = eval(httpxml.responseText);
        // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
        for (j = document.testform.subcat.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
          document.testform.subcat.remove(j);
        }
        for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
          var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
          optn.text = myarray[i];
          optn.value = myarray[i];
          document.testform.subcat.options.add(optn);
        } 
      }
    }
    var url="dd.php";
    url = url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
    url = url+"&sid="+Math.random();
    httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateck;
    httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
    httpxml.send(null);
  }

</script>

<form name="testform" method='POST' action='mainck.php'>Name:<input type=text name=fname>
Select first one <select name=cat onchange="AjaxFunction(this.value);">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<?

  require "config.php";// connection to database 
  $q=mysql_query("select * from categories");
  while($n=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    echo "<option value=$n[cat_id]>$n[category]</option>";
  }

?>
</select>

<select name=subcat>

</select><input type=submit value=submit>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**and dd.php is**

```
<?

  $cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
  require "config.php";
  $q=mysql_query("select subcategory from subcategory where cat_id='$cat_id'");
  echo mysql_error();
  $myarray=array();
  $str="";
  while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
    $str=$str . "\"$nt[subcategory]\"".",";
  }
  $str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string
  echo "new Array($str)";

?>
```

As mentioned, main.php loads and populates the first drop down box correctly. Once a value is chosen nothing appears in the second box. To test, I changed the mysql query in dd.php from

```
$q=mysql_query("select subcategory from subcategory where cat_id='$cat_id'");
```

to

```
$q=mysql_query("select subcategory from subcategory where cat_id=1");
```

This then populates the second box when a 'category' is chosen. I think the chosen value is not passing from main.php to dd.php correctly with the

```
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
```

Any help on this would be appreciated. I have a feeling this is something small but cant quite put my finger on it.

As always many thanks in advance.
**UPDATED QUESTION**

**main.php**

```
<form name='testform' method='POST' action='mainck.php'> 
      Name: <input type='text' name='fname'> 
      Select first one 
      <select name='cat' onchange='AjaxFunction(this);'> 
        <option value=''>Select One</option> 

<?php 

  require "config.php";// connection to database 

  // I will continue to use mysql_query(), but please migrate you code to 
  // PDO or MySQLi ASAP 
  $query = " 
    SELECT cat_id,category 
    FROM categories
  "; 
  $result = mysql_query($query); 

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo "<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$row['category']}</option>"; 
  } 

?> 

      </select> 
      <select name='subcat' id='subcat_select'> 
      </select> 
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'> 
    </form>
```

**dd.php**

```
<?php 

  require "config.php"; 

  $query = " 
   SELECT packcode 
    FROM skudata
    WHERE cat_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat_id'])."'       "; 
  $result = mysql_query($query); 

  $array = array(); 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    $array[] = $row['packcode']; 
  } 

  echo json_encode($array); 

?>
```

with the changes Dave Added, I cant get the new mysql tables and reference columns working. Have tested the mysql and it works well. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
URL overwrite i guess

Comment: Hi Swapnesh, thanks for this. I changed these two lines without success. any other advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the small thing that is preventing you code from working is the value your are passing to the function. For a `<select>` element `this.value` will not work. Instead, you need to use `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`. Like so:

```
<select name=cat onchange="AjaxFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
```

Now for some comments about your code:

- *Never* use `eval()`. Ever. In any language. The correct use cases are so few and far between that it's much simpler to just say "Never use it".
- Don't use the `mysql` extension. Use [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`MySQLi`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.
- You have a huge [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) hole in your code.
- Please indent your code sensibly. It makes it much easier to debug. That higgledy-piggledy lump you posted was almost impossible to read.
- Don't use `document.elementName` to access elements on the page. Give your elements ID's and use `document.getElementById('elementId')` instead - it works everywhere, which named elements does not.
- Don't use PHP short open tags `<?`, use the full `<?php` tag - again, it works everywhere, which short tags do not.

Here is how I would write your code:

*main.php*

```
<html>

  <head>
    <!-- Omitting the <head> is very bad practice... -->
    <title>My Page</title>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

      function GetAjaxObject () {
        // Wrap the code for fetching an AJAX object in a separate function
        // so it can be easily re-used
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest !== undefined) {
          return new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        var xhr = null;
        var axo = ['Msxml2.XMLHTTP', 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP'];
        for (var o in axo) {
          try {
            xhr = new ActiveXObject(axo[o]); 
          } catch (e) {}
        }
        if (xhr !== null) {
          return xhr;
        } else {
          throw new Error('Your browser does not support AJAX');
        }
      }

      function ChangeSelect (element) {

        // We are now passing the select element itself in, not just a value

        var xhr, url;

        // Fetch an AJAX object
        try {
          var xhr = GetAjaxObject();
        } catch (e) {
          alert(e.message);
          return;
        }

        // Build the URL
        url = "dd.php"
            + "?cat_id="+element.options[element.selectedIndex].value
            + "&sid="+Math.random();

        // If it still doesn't work, uncomment this line to inspect the url
        // alert(url);

        // Define the readystatechange callback        
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) { // Don't forget to check the status code

              // I shall leave this eval() here for now, but really you should
              // use a safe JSON library like http://www.json.org/js.html
              var myarray = eval(httpxml.responseText);

              // Start by getting a safe reference to the destination select
              var dest = document.getElementById('subcat_select');

              // Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
              for (j = dest.options.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                dest.remove(j);
              }

              // Loop data from the server and create new options
              for (i = 0; i < myarray.length; i++) {
                var optn = document.createElement("option");
                optn.text = myarray[i];
                optn.value = myarray[i];
                dest.options.add(optn);
              } 

            } else {
              alert("Server returned error " + xhr.status);
            }
          }
        };

        // Start the request
        httpxml.open("GET", url, true);
        httpxml.send(null);

      }

    </script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <form name='testform' method='POST' action='mainck.php'>
      Name: <input type='text' name='fname'>
      Select first one
      <select name='cat' onchange='AjaxFunction(this);'>
        <option value=''>Select One</option>

<?php

  require "config.php";// connection to database

  // I will continue to use mysql_query(), but please migrate you code to
  // PDO or MySQLi ASAP
  $query = "
    SELECT *
    FROM categories
  ";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$row['category']}</option>";
  }

?>

      </select>
      <select name='subcat' id='subcat_select'>
      </select>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

*dd.php*

```
<?php

  require "config.php";

  $query = "
    SELECT subcategory
    FROM subcategory
    WHERE cat_id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['cat_id'])."'
  ";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  $array = array();
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $array[] = $row['subcategory'];
  }

  echo json_encode($array);

?>
```

Comment: Select first one <select name=cat onchange="AjaxFunction(this.value);">

Comment: Select first one <select name=cat onchange="AjaxFunction(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);"> . this is not working however. any other areas of the code that is incorrect?

Comment: @Smudger Give me a few minutes, I will post how I would write the code.

Comment: @Smudger See edit above. Feel free to ask any questions about it

Comment: Thanks Dave, you have given me allot of help hear. It is working 100%, I'll need to go through it to make sure I understand it correctly. Willd efinately post here if I have any questions. Thanks a million.

Comment: Hi Dave, I have edited the question, just struggling with the change of mysql tables being returned. Please assist if possible. Thanks,

Comment: @Smudger So am I right in saying that all you have changed is the query in `dd.php`?

Comment: @Smudger Oh wait, I also notice you have changed the `action=` attribute of the form - did you remember to rename `dd.php` to `mainck.php`?

Comment: Hi Dave, working 100%. Thanks again for the help and guidance.

Answer (score 1):

this code not worknig as all this is main.php file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function AjaxFunction(cat_id)
{
var httpxml;
try
  {
  // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
  httpxml=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
catch (e)
  {
  // Internet Explorer
          try
                    {
                 httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                    }
            catch (e)
                    {
                try
            {
            httpxml=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
             }
                catch (e)
            {
            alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
            return false;
            }
            }
  }
function stateck() 
    {
    if(httpxml.readyState==4)
      {

var myarray=eval(httpxml.responseText);
// Before adding new we must remove previously loaded elements
for(j=document.testform.subcat.options.length-1;j>=0;j--)
{
document.testform.subcat.remove(j);
}


for (i=0;i<myarray.length;i++)
{
var optn = document.createElement("OPTION");
optn.text = myarray[i];
optn.value = myarray[i];
document.testform.subcat.options.add(optn);

} 
      }
    }
    var url="dd.php";
url=url+"?cat_id="+cat_id;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
httpxml.onreadystatechange=stateck;
httpxml.open("GET",url,true);
httpxml.send(null);
  }
</script>

<form name="testform" method='POST' action='mainck.php'>
Select first one <select name=cat onchange="AjaxFunction(this.value);">
<option value=''>Select One</option>
<?
require "config.php";// connection to database 
$q=mysql_query("select * from it_category ");
while($n=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
echo "<option value=$n[cat_id]>$n[category]</option>";
}

?>
</select>

<select name=subcat>

</select><input type=submit value=submit>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and this is dd.php

```
<?
$cat_id=$_GET['cat_id'];
require "config.php";
$q=mysql_query("select * from it_subcategory where cat_id='$cat_id'");
echo mysql_error();
$myarray=array();
$str="";
while($nt=mysql_fetch_array($q)){
$str=$str . "\"$nt[subcategory]\"".",";
}
$str=substr($str,0,(strLen($str)-1)); // Removing the last char , from the string
echo "new Array($str)";

?>
```

Comment: Would you please describe why and how your answer solves the question?