# How to populate values in drop down from select query on other dropdown?

Tags: javascript

How can i populate the values in the drop down(second drop down) from the select query on choosing
the option from the first drop down ?

Examples:
First Drop Down : Listing out all the "department name" using select query.
Second Drop Down : Now, i need the output to list out all the "professors name" in the respective departments on the basis of the first drop down option.

Thanks in advance. Much Appreciated your help.

Answer (score 2):

You could easily accomplish this with JavaScript: http://javascript.about.com/library/bl3drop.htm

This essentially uses if-then statements to output the latter dropdown lists with options dependent on the first. If you're looking more for PHP and Ajax (for dynamic lists from a database), this is a similar question: [[link]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783686/dynamic-drop-down-list-php-and-javascript)

Comment: Hi, In javascript, two drop down values should come from the database select query. One drop down values should be depends on the other drop down values. I don't want to hard code any values in the drop down, it's should come from the database. Thanks. Give me some sample coding.

Comment: @jacksantho - You'll want to simply do PHP foreach loops. And echo/print the JS from that.

Comment: Hi, can you give some sample coding please.

Comment: @jacksantho - Tomorrow when it's not early in the morning and I have some time, I'll try to make you an outline or example of what you should do.